# Apache Flink: how to consume dynamic type in transformation (map, reduce, join, etc) functions

Tags: java, dynamic, apache-flink

I create a custom csv reader that generates a dynamic return type specified with `env.readCsvFile(location).pojoType(dynClass, arr);`, where `dynClass` is created with ByteBuddy and `arr` is an array of column names. I then try to map my pojo to a tuple with:

```
public class PojoToTupleRichMapFunction extends RichMapFunction<I, O> implements ResultTypeQueryable {

    Class tupleClass = null;
    Class pojoClass = null;
    Config.Schema schema = null;
    transient List<Field> fields = null;

    PojoToTupleRichMapFunction(DynDataSet dynSet) {
        this.schema = dynSet.dataDef.schema;
        // Create a map from pojo to tuple
        this.tupleClass = O.getTupleClass(schema.columns.size());
        this.pojoClass = dynSet.recType;

    }

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) {
        fields = new ArrayList<>(schema.columns.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < schema.columns.size(); i++) {
            try {
                fields.add(pojoClass.getField(schema.columns.get(i).name));
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PojoToTupleRichMapFunction.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public TupleTypeInfo getProducedType() {
        // build list of types
        List<BasicTypeInfo<?>> types = new ArrayList<>(schema.columns.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < schema.columns.size(); i++) {
            BasicTypeInfo bt = null;
            String typeName = schema.columns.get(i).type.getName();
            switch (typeName) {
                case "java.lang.Integer":
                    bt = BasicTypeInfo.INT_TYPE_INFO;
                    break;
                case "java.lang.String":
                    bt = BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO;
                    break;
                case "java.lang.Long":
                    bt = BasicTypeInfo.LONG_TYPE_INFO;
                    break;
                case "java.lang.Short":
                    bt = BasicTypeInfo.SHORT_TYPE_INFO;
                    break;
                default:
                    Logger.getLogger(Config.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Unknown type: {0}", typeName);

            }
            types.add(bt);
        }
        return new TupleTypeInfo(tupleClass, types.toArray(new BasicTypeInfo[0]));
    }

    @Override
    public O map(I pojo) throws Exception {
        O ret;
        ret = (O) tupleClass.newInstance();
        for (int i = 0; i < schema.columns.size(); i++) {
            ret.setField(fields.get(i).get(pojo), i);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

The challenge I am running into is this runtime error fragment:
`org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.InvalidTypesException: Input mismatch: POJO type 'com.me.dynamic.FlinkPojo$ByteBuddy$zQ9VllB1' expected but was 'com.me.dynamic.I'.`

The function declaration specifies base types. The actual input type is a dynamic subclass. The output type is provided by getProducedType.

How do I craft the MapFunction to handle the dynamic input type?

Comment: Made some edits to the above to show that creating the fields array should be done in the `open` method so that the `fields` data isn't lost during serialization.

Answer (score 0):

To provide at least one solution (perhaps not the best), I changed the class definition to:

```
public class PojoToTupleRichMapFunction<I extends FlinkPojo, O extends Tuple> extends RichMapFunction<I, O> implements ResultTypeQueryable {
}
```

I then used ByteBuddy to reclassify a the compiled class containing generic parameters.

```
static private DataSet<?> mapPojoToTuple(DataSet ds, DynDataSet dynSet) {
    Class<?> clazz = new ByteBuddy()
        .subclass(TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.parameterizedType(PojoToTupleRichMapFunction.class, dynSet.recType, Tuple.class).build())
        .make()
        .load(PojoToTupleRichMapFunction.class.getClassLoader())
        .getLoaded();
    Constructor<?> ctr = clazz.getConstructors()[0];
    RichMapFunction fcn = null;
    try {
        fcn = (RichMapFunction) ctr.newInstance(dynSet);
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(dyn_demo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return ds.map(fcn);
}
```

This seems to satisfy Flink.